# Why does vscode console shows debug failed, even though it didn't?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, console

From my workspace configuration:

```
{
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name"             : "Debug Current",
                "type"             : "node",
                "request"          : "launch",
                "cwd"              : "${fileDirname}",
                "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
                "runtimeArgs"      : ["run-script", "debug"],
                "port"             : 9229,
                "sourceMaps"       : true,
                "console"          : "integratedTerminal",
            },
        ],
        "compounds": []
    }
}
```

Triggers the script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "debug": "node -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk=9229 src/index.ts"
}
```

Where `index.ts` is just a simple:

```
console.log('test')

// process.exit(0) // does nothing
```

And the console outputs:

```
Debugger attached.
test
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! __PACKAGE.NAME@0.0.0 debug: `node -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk=9229 src/index.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the __PACKAGE.NAME@0.0.0 debug script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

While the usual console does not have this issue. But I need this console to deal with user input.

From what I've tested, this happens **only** when the debbuger connects. This does not happen with:

`node -r ts-node/register src/index.ts # exit code === 0`

Any idea why the debugger causes this?

Comment: any more info or is there an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?